# Replacing parts of a string containing directory paths using Python

Tags: python, string, directory, substring

I have a large string with potentially many paths in it resembling this structure:

> dirA/dirB/a1ed4f3b-a046-4fbf-bb70-0774bd7bfcn

and I need to replace everything before the `a1ed4f3b-a046-4fbf-bb70-0774bd7bfcn` part of the string with "`local/`" such that the 
result will look like this:

> local/a1ed4f3b-a046-4fbf-bb70-0774bd7bfcn

The string could contain more than just dirA/dirB/ at 
the start of the string too.

How can I do this string manipulation in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using regular expressions, you can replace everything up to and including the last `"/"` with `"locals/"`

```
import re
s = "dirA/dirB/a1ed4f3b-a046-4fbf-bb70-0774bd7bfcn"
re.sub(r'.*(\/.*)',r'local\1',s)
```

and you obtain:

```
'local/a1ed4f3b-a046-4fbf-bb70-0774bd7bfcn'
```

Comment: the char `/` doesn't need to be escaped

Comment: TYVM @Tomerikoo :)

Comment: I like the change but it's still escaped haha you can change `(\/.*)` to `(/.*)` in the first regex

Answer (score 3):

Use `os` module

**Ex:**

```
import os


path = "dirA/dirB/a1ed4f3b-a046-4fbf-bb70-0774bd7bfcn"
print(os.path.join("locals", os.path.basename(path)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to split the string on `"/"` and then concatenate `"locals/"` with the last element of the resultant list.

```
s = "dirA/dirB/a1ed4f3b-a046-4fbf-bb70-0774bd7bfcn"
print("locals/" + s.split("/")[-1])
#'locals/a1ed4f3b-a046-4fbf-bb70-0774bd7bfcn'
```

Answer (score 0):

How does this look?

```
inputstring = 'dirA/dirB/a1ed4f3b-a046-4fbf-bb70-0774bd7bfcn'
filename = os.path.basename(inputstring)
localname =  'local'
os.path.join(localname, filename)
```

Comment: Or just `"local/" + os.path.basename(inputstring)`

Comment: @Tomerikoo . . . true, but I believe os.path.join() will format it in a manner consistent with the operating system so it will work in any environment.  Linux uses forward slashes and Windows uses backslashes.